# Why i am getting error while calling api with provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm calling a API and saving its response using providers so that i can access from anywhere in my flutter app. The model used for storing response is

```
class Album with ChangeNotifier {
      final String id;
      final List<String> categoriesId;
      final String title;
      final String imageUrl;

      Album({this.id, this.categoriesId, this.title, this.imageUrl});

      factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
            List<dynamic> res = json['category_list'];
            List<String> cats = [];
            res.forEach((tx) {
                cats.add(tx.toString());
            });
            return Album(
                id: json['id'].toString(),
                categoriesId: cats,
                title: json['name'],
                imageUrl: json["image"],
            );
      }
}
```

While the function calling endpoint is,

```
String albumUrl = "http://192.168.227.102:9000/static/album.json";

Future<List<Album>> fetchAnime(BuildContext context) async {
  List<Album> resAlbum = [];
  try {
     final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(albumUrl));
     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       List<dynamic> result = jsonDecode(response.body)['album'];
       result.forEach((tx) {
          Album test = Anime.fromJson(tx as Map<String, dynamic>);
          resAlbum.add(test);
       });
     }
   } catch (e) {
     print(e);
 }
  return resAlbum;
}
```

The provider for model `Album` is,

```
class AlbumProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Album> _items = [];

  void getPostData(context) async {
     bool loading = true;
     if (this._items.isNotEmpty) {
        this._items = await fetchAlbum(context);
     }
     loading = false;
     notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The view using this provider is,

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
   void initState() {
     Provider.of<AlbumProvider>(context, listen: false).getPostData(context);
     super.initState();
   }
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       List<Album> albumData = Provider.of<AlbumProvider>(context).allitems;
       return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
           title: Text(
             'Home Screen',
           ),
         ),
         body:albumData.isEmpty
            ?Text("we are fetching data")
            :Text("fetching complete")
         )
     }
  }
```

When i run the app i got following error,

> The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for AlbumProvider:
> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

> This _InheritedProviderScope widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
> The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: _InheritedProviderScope

What are the reasons for getting the error and How can i remove this error?

Comment: Where is the allitems variable?

Answer (score 1):

This is because, when you are calling

```
Provider.of<AlbumProvider>(context, listen: false).getPostData(context);
```

from initState method of HomePage, which in turn invokes following method

```
  void getPostData(context) async {
     bool loading = true;
     if (this._items.isNotEmpty) {
        this._items = await fetchAlbum(context);
     }
     loading = false;
     notifyListeners();
  }
```

This function is calling notifiyListeners();
The issue is that you are listening for changes to `AlbumProvider` in build method of HomePage.

```
 List<Album> albumData = Provider.of<AlbumProvider>(context).allitems;
```

So ultimately, `initState` is calling `getPostData` which is calling `notifyListeners()` which will try to rebuild the widget tree before it has finished building.

You should `FutureBuilder` instead of calling `getPostData()` in the `initState` method.